# PHP failed to copy folder A to folder B

Tags: php

i have found some coding from SOF and try to copy folder, however, i got error messages. I tried the coding on localhost -> XAMPP

**Coding**

```
function recurse_copy($src,$dst) { 
    $dir = opendir($src); 
    @mkdir($dst); 
    while(false !== ( $file = readdir($dir)) ) { 
        if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) { 
            if ( is_dir($src . '/' . $file) ) { 
                recurse_copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
            } 
            else { 
                copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    closedir($dir); 
}
$current_dir=basename(__DIR__) ;
$src=$current_dir."/img";
$dst=$current_dir."/img2";


recurse_copy($src, $dst);
```

**error message**

```
Warning: opendir(hk_domain/img,hk_domain/img): ϵͳ�Ҳ���ָ����·���� (code: 3) in C:\xampp\htdocs\hk_domain\copy.php on line 4

Warning: opendir(hk_domain/img): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\hk_domain\copy.php on line 4

Warning: readdir() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\hk_domain\copy.php on line 6

Warning: copy(hk_domain/img/): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\hk_domain\copy.php on line 12

Warning: readdir() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\hk_domain\copy.php on line 6`
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: check that directory is present or not and have correct permission (755) or not?

Comment: @AlivetoDie I running it localhost , the director is present

Comment: what about read-write permission that i told you. You need to check parent directory also have 755 permission too

Comment: @AlivetoDie i already figure out the problem. Simply change the $src to 'img' and $dst to 'img2' . thx anyway